# Use alias for column name in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose if I have a SQLAlchemy table as follows -

```
class Employee(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_desgination = Column(String)
```

I remember going through the docs once and seeing some way of using aliases for long column names and use shorter ones instead. For example, in the above table instead of calling `Employee.employee_designation` I'd like to use `Employee.emp_d` or something similar. I wasn't able to find the example again :/ I think you declare an `alias()` in the table definition, but I am not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can specify the [actual column name](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-with-mapped-column) (if different from the attribute name) as the first argument to `Column`:

```
emp_d = Column("employee_desgination", String)
```

Comment: That's still really helpful, I was trying to go around using the keyword 'pass' and finally found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the table already exist you can reference to the fields directly:

```
class Humans(Base):
    __table__ = people_table
    id = people_table.c.PeopleID
    name = people_table.c.PeopleName
```

Answer (score 0):

// tested on sqlalchemy1.4

if use this form define: // for others come here

```
sqlalchemy.Table('sometable', metadata, 
  Column('from', Intege)
)
```

alias can be define by this:

```
t1 = Table('sometable', metadata, 
  Column('from', Integer, key='from_')
)
```

and use column by

```
t1.c.from_
```

but, in result, still use  `record.from`

ref:
https://groups.google.com/g/sqlalchemy/c/0mV5R2KUZgI/m/fpI7dC_mGrsJ