# SQLAlchemy column name is reserved in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy and I want to insert some data. I have a column named 'class' which I have to insert into and of course Python errors due to it's reserved keyword list:

```
                self.db_connection.execute( self.common_template_table.insert().values(template_label=label,
                                                                                       **class**=class_of_template,
                                                                                       security_level=security_level,
                                                                                       condition=condtion,
                                                                                       template_type=type,
                                                                                       aco_id=aco_id,
                                                                                       service_id=service_id, 
                                                                                       translation_id=translation_id,
                                                                                       connect_point_id=cp_id, 
                                                                                       schema_enforcement_id=schema_id,
                                                                                       template_id=temp_object.id ))
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: `.values(..., **{'class':class_of_template})` Python does not do those checks when unpacking

Comment: I was also looking for an answer to this and found this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758128/use-alias-for-column-name-in-sqlalchemy)