# Flask-Admin: Workaround for fields with reserved names

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-admin

I want to use `flask-admin` for an existing table which has a column named meta but `flask-admin` doesn't support this as it uses `WTForms` for which `meta` is a reserved keyword. I can not use an alias for this column as a lot of code is already written using this name.

Is there any way to make this work?

Or is there any other python package that works with `SQLAlchemy` while providing similar features to `flask-admin` or `django-admin`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use alias for column name in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758128/use-alias-for-column-name-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: It does not solve the issue as other services already use this field and it would mean changes in a all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `flask-admin`, but I had similar issue and I solved it with `synonym`.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import synonym

class SomeTable(Model):
    # Normal model definition here
    ...
    meta_data = synonym('meta')
```

You can use `meta_data` as a field in your form.